# What is the process to start a moderator election at a site that needs one?

Tags: support, election, moderators

As per [this thread on The Pro Webmaster Meta](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/when-will-we-have-elections/799#comment981_799), we're down to two mods and could use a third (one recently quit). What is the process to getting an election started to get us back to three moderators? Who do we notify?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You gotta talk to us - the community team.

Drop us an email (`community@`) and describe your situation. You can also ping [any one of us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-managers-and-what-do-they-do) in chat.

For completeness, this applies to graduated sites that have already had an election after graduating. We don't generally run elections on beta sites unless there is a moderation gap that needs to be filled. Also, we have a set process for determining when a graduating site is ready to support its first election after graduation.